# how to concatenate two variables only if both value assigned to both variables in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

how to concatenate two variables only if both value assigned to both variables ?

```
1. Assign $SERVER to $NODELIST if only $SERVER variable is set
2. Assign $NODE to $NODELIST if only $NODE variable is set
3. Concatenate $SERVER and $NODE [comma separated ]to $NODELIST if both $SERVER and $NODE is set

#!/bin/bash
SERVER='sn01,sn02'
NODE='cn01,cn02'

if [[ -z $SERVER ]] || [[ -z $NODE ]] ; then
NODE_LIST=$SERVER,$NODE
echo "$NODE_LIST"
elif [[ -z $SERVER ]] || [[ -z $NODE ]] ; then
NODE_LIST=$SERVER
echo "$NODE_LIST"
elif [[ -z $NODE ]] || [[ -z  $SERVER ]] ; then
NODE_LIST=$NODE
echo "NODE_LIST"
else
echo "none of the variables specified"
fi
```

but couldn't assign the "NODE_LIST" Variables as per the requirement.

Comment: You may use: `[[ -n $SERVER  && -n $NODE ]] && NODE_LIST="$SERVER,$NODE"`

Comment: if [[ -n $SERVER && -n $NODE ]] ; then
NODE_LIST="$SERVER,$NODE"
echo $NODE_LIST
fi

Comment: how to Assign $SERVER to $NODELIST if only $SERVER variable is set and how to Assign $NODE to $NODELIST if only $NODE variable is set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array for this and append an element in array if it is not empty.

```
#!/bin/bash
server='sn01,sn02'
node='cn01,cn02'

arr=()
[[ -n $server ]] && arr+=("$server")
[[ -n $node ]] && arr+=("$node")

# print comma delimited output using all array elements
IFS=, && echo "${arr[*]}"
```

PS: I have changes uppercase variable names to lowercase to avoid potential conflicts with environment variables.

Comment: Works, thank you. how to store this comma separated variable to array, so I can input it to another command

Comment: You already have this in array `arr`. To store it in a string use: `IFS=, && str="${arr[*]}"`

Answer (score 2):

Something like,

```
$ [[ -z "$SERVER" || -z "$NODE" ]] && NODELIST="$SERVER$NODE"
```

Answer (score 0):

-z returns TRUE if your string is NULL or empty. So the output is correct since both of your strings are not null. try to null either $NODE or $SERVER. you will get the $NODE_LIST